# Ember.js parent/child relationships

Tags: ember.js

I have the following data structure for a simple messaging app:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  body: DS.attr("string"),
  isRead: DS.attr("boolean"),
  replyTo: DS.belongsTo("App.Message")
});

App.Message.FIXTURES = [{
  id: "1",
  title: "Eos ut amet persius, ea ius nibh iudico",
  body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam et hinc doctus alienum, in vel latine conceptam.",
  isRead: true,
  replyTo: null
},
{
  id: "2",
  title: "Ad est dolor veniam delenit.",
  body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam et hinc doctus alienum, in vel latine conceptam.",
  isRead: false,
  replyTo: "1"
},
{
  id: "3",
  title: "Eu nec summo placerat reprehendunt.",
  body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam et hinc doctus alienum, in vel latine conceptam. Tale eirmod omittantur sit ne. Minim noster philosophia per eu, mel putent veritus an, ex veniam ubique consulatu has. At stet diceret repudiare ius, probo liber diceret no est. Ridens efficiantur vim te.",
  isRead: false,
  replyTo: "1"
}];
```

**I am trying to display replies to a message when it is selected but none are appearing.**  The message subject and body *are* displaying fine so I know my routes, controllers and templates are set up correctly for the parent entity at least.

Here are my templates (with almost all markup removed for brevity):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="message">      
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>        
  <p>{{ body }}</p>
  {{ render "messageResponses" responses }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="messageResponses">
  {{#each responses}}
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

And my Message controller (the part I'm probably doing wrong):

```
App.MessageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  responses: function() {
    return App.Message.find({ replyTo: this.get("id") );  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `findProperty` instead:

```
App.MessageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  responses: function() {
    return App.Message.findProperty('replyTo', this.get("id"));  
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it.  I'm actually trying with `App.Message.find()` which I know works and still nothing.

Comment: Then how about this, assuming you have the model: `messageModel.get('replyTo');`? That should return you the reply to message.